# Runtime Error no Python

Tags: python, runtime

Fiz um programa backtracking no Python para encontrar um conjunto de tamanho M de strings binárias onde qualquer string tenha distância maior que d para qualquer outra string do conjunto.

Mas não funciona bem quando testo para n = 8. Aparece a mensagem:

> "Runtime error! This application has requested the runtime to
>   terminate it in an unusual way"

Alguém sabe por quê?

Código:

```
def dist(a,b):
 k = 0 
 for i in range (0,20):
    if a%2 != b%2:
      k = k + 1
    a = a/2
    b = b/2 
 return k 

def bin(n):
 nd = 0
 pot = 1
 while (n  0):
    nd = nd + n%2 * pot
    n = n/2
    pot = pot * 10
 return nd

o = []
o = o + [0]
M = 4
n = 5
d = 3
Tam = 2**n - 1

def cod(ult):
 j = ult
 while j < Tam+1: 
  aux = 0
  for i in range (0,len(o)): 
     if dist(o[i],j+1)  d-1: 
       aux += 1 
  if aux == len(o): 
     o.append(j+1) 
     j +=1
  else:
     j+=1
 return (o)   

cod(0)

while len(o) < M+1:
  if len(o)  M-1:
     for i in range (0,len(o)):
       print bin(o[i])
     print o
     print len(o)
     break
  else:
     ult = o.pop() 
     cod(ult)
```

Comment: Mudei `n = 5` pra `n = 8`, testei e não ocorreu o erro.

Comment: Qual versão do python vc está usando?

Comment: Sim, Luiz, com valores menores de n, não ocorre erro. 

Tenho instalada a versão 2.7 e também tentei rodar online, no repl.it e trava em certo momento...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segundo o [report](http://bugs.python.org/issue9890) existe um bug presente na versão Python 2.6, basicamente uma solução para este problema foi alterando o caminho da variável ambiente pythonhome de python26 para python32

Comment: Uso a versão 2.7. Ainda seria uma solução? (Não entendo muito...)

Comment: acredito que seria a mesma solução, vc precisa entrar nas variáveis de ambiente e mudar o valor da variavel `pythonhome` da pasta do python26 para python32 geralmente no Windows a pasta fica em `C:/.../python26` e `C:/.../python32`

Comment: Olha, acho que funcionou. Tá rodando há um tempão e não dá erro. Obrigada!